# D3 invalid character in element

Tags: mongodb, d3.js

I'm getting a response in JSON format, which contains an `_id` that is stored as an ObjectID in Mongodb on the server side. However, I change it into a String, and it still won't let me add it. Is it because it has numbers? I need the element to be identifiable by the id, so if I can't append this way, is there any other way I can reference the element by the id?

```
var group = d3.select("#containerthing");
var id = response._id.toString();
console.log(id);
//5802bc044f6313c1097de4a2
var responseNode = group.append(id).attr("fill","black").attr("x", 15).attr("y", 15).attr("width", 190).attr("height", 90);
//InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character
```

Comment: Why you need to append to _id? I've seen that in append function, always pass a HTML element as an argument.

Comment: @SebastianLorenzo I'm not appending to the _id. To my understanding, _id represents the element name of sorts that d3 uses. If I replace `_id` with `'foo'`, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that I understand your problem.

D3's [.append()](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_append):

> If the specified type is a string, appends a new element of this type (tag name) as the last child of each selected element, or the next following sibling in the update selection if this is an enter selection. [...] This function should return an element to be appended. (The function typically creates a new element, but it may instead return an existing element.

Why .append() work fine if you pass `'foo'`? Because D3 append a custom tag element. If you see in your console I'am sure that you will see `<foo>...</foo>`

Why .append() work wrong if you pass `'5802bc044f6313c1097de4a2'`? A custom tag element can't start with a number. You don't use `_id`, you should try to find another pattern for identify your element.

I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that you can't start elements with numbers. I had to do:

```
var responseNode = group.append("n"+id).attr("fill","black").attr("x", 15).attr("y", 15).attr("width", 190).attr("height", 90);
```

to get it to work.